Replace fabric roof on gazebo for metal or hard top material
I have a a steel frame gazebo with ripped canopy. Therefore, I was thinking of replacing the canopy with hard top. I have started my research and I arrived at these options 1- Ondura corrugated panel (Asphalt/fiberglass) which is around $22 a panel 2- Suntuf corrugated panel (polycarbonate) which is around $55 a panel.
Obviously I would opt in for the cheaper option but is there a strong reason I should go (or should not go) with one or the other? Or perhaps another panel I am not aware of.
Can these panels be installed on the steel beams directly ( beams are like this)
enter image description here
The gazebo frame I have is 10 by 12

Are you sure the gazebo frame can handle the additional weight, especially under heavy wind or under a snow load?
